# Show submit button on multiple forms only if option selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I need to show the submit button on many forms on the same page only if one option from a select is selected.

I have:

```html
<form id="1">
    <input type="text">
    <select>
        <option value="">Select one value</option>
        <option value="1">value 1</option>
        <option value="2">value 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

and

<form id="2">
  <input type="text">
  <select>
    <option value="">Select one value</option>
    <option value="1">value 1</option>
    <option value="2">value 2</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

so, I need to show the submit button only if an option of the select is selected
Thanks!!!

Comment: learn some javascript and jquery first, then come to SO

Comment: what you have tried so far????

Comment: [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/change/) you will find everything you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a working example with you html http://jsfiddle.net/g188o5eg/

```
    $('select').on('change', function(){
        if($(this).val() != ''){
             $(this).parent().find('input[type="submit"]').show();   
        } else {
            $(this).parent().find('input[type="submit"]').hide(); 
        }
    });
```

It will work with all forms on your site :)

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly! I try it for a few hours but  I didn't get a working result (for many forms, because for only one is simple...)

Comment: Great, glad that I could help. Now you can accept this answer :)

Comment: :( :( :( "Vote Up requires 15 reputation"

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (would work with multiple select boxes (uses the nearest submit):

```
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <select class="select">
    <option value="">Select one value</option>
    <option value="1">value 1</option>
    <option value="2">value 2</option>
  </select>
 <input type="submit" class="submitbutton">
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.submitbutton').hide();

$('.select').click(function() {
   $(this).closest('.submitbutton').show();
});

</script>
```